# How can I colorize and format my vs code terminal to look like the example below

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

The vs code terminal I'm aiming is something like the Fireship's terminal. In this example, Fireship (content-creator in youtube) made a rust program, but in my case I'm trying to make it out with python 3.x.  My mainly goal with this is making reading terminal easier and more intuitive.

[Fireship's VsCode Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lktj.png)

[My VsCode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vbvC.png)

Comment: if the python extension does not use ANSI Color codes you don't get color, the Rust compiler uses a lot of ANSI Color codes

Comment: Well, that's a shame. I guess I'll go stick with an IDE while learning the basics until I really need programming in python on VS Code.

Comment: it is not python on VSC, Python just don't use ANSI Colors

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors yourself if you want in the workbench settings.json
Steps:

1. Open Settings (Ctrl + ,)
2. Search for workbench color
3. Click on `edit in settings.json`

You can find out about the different settings you can change [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#integrated-terminal-colors)
An example of how you can change your terminal:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.background":"#131212",
    "terminal.foreground":"#dddad6",
    "terminal.ansiBlack":"#1D2021",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlack":"#665C54",
    "terminal.ansiBrightBlue":"#0D6678",
    "terminal.ansiBrightCyan":"#8BA59B",
    "terminal.ansiBrightGreen":"#237e02",
    "terminal.ansiBrightMagenta":"#8F4673",
    "terminal.ansiBrightRed":"#FB543F",
    "terminal.ansiBrightWhite":"#FDF4C1",
    "terminal.ansiBrightYellow":"#FAC03B",
    "terminal.ansiBlue":"#00a1f9",
    "terminal.ansiCyan":"#8BA59B",
    "terminal.ansiGreen":"#95C085",
    "terminal.ansiMagenta":"#8F4673",
    "terminal.ansiRed":"#FB543F",
    "terminal.ansiWhite":"#A89984",
    "terminal.ansiYellow":"#FAC03B"
},
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this one and even searched the documentation you provided for more information but unfortunately nothing changed, it's still plain white